# How to make css counter works with css selector?

Tags: html, css

I'was trying to use css counter...
This is my css code:

```
div.primaries div.entries>div.meaning:first-child:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section);
}
```

and the part of html

```
<div class="primaries">
<div class="headword entries">
<div class="meaning terms">
<span class="meaning terms text">A collection of items of the ...</span>
</div>
<div class="meaning entries">
<div class="example terms">
<span class="example terms text">an arms <em>cache</em></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="meaning entries">
<div class="example terms">
<span class="example terms text">a <em>cache</em> of gold coins</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="headword entries">
<div class="meaning terms">
<span class="meaning terms text">A hidden or inaccessible ...</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="headword entries">
<div class="meaning terms">
<span class="meaning terms text">An auxiliary memory from ...</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I did not use any "counter-reset".
However, every number outputed was 1.
So, why it is always 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this and I think it will do as you will:

```
div.primaries
{
  counter-reset: section;
}
```

See it work at [jsfiddle/Larry/ev758/](http://jsfiddle.net/Larry/ev758/).

Comment: From w3schools: "The counter-reset property creates or resets one or more counters."

Comment: @elric, if this works for you, please [mark it as answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).